# Ubuntu device-specific bluetooth widget

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, widget

I wanted to see if there was a way to program a very simplistic-looking GUI (an on/off switch button) to connect to a specific bluetooth device using the command *bluetoothctl*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I've done it.

1. A script to toggle connection
2. A menu shortcut to call the script

The script, which I placed in ~/.local/bin (any place is good):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import check_output, call


def is_connected(device_mac):
    return b'Connected: yes\n' in check_output(['bluetoothctl', 'info', device_mac])

def connect(device_mac):
    print('connecting to bluetooth device {}'.format(device_mac))
    call(['bluetoothctl', 'connect', device_mac])

def disconnect(device_mac):
    print('disconnecting from bluetooth device {}'.format(device_mac))
    call(['bluetoothctl', 'disconnect', device_mac])

def main(device_mac):
    if is_connected(device_mac):
        disconnect(device_mac)
    else:
        connect(device_mac)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('04:5D:4B:E9:29:D4')
```

Find your device MAC address in the list of your added devices:

```
$ bluetoothctl devices
```

And replace the MAC address '04:5D:4B:E9:29:D4' to your device's MAC address.

Then I created a menu shortcut by creating a `.desktop` file. You can put it on your ~/Desktop to see it on your... desktop or/and in ~/.local/share/applications to have it available from the launcher menu.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=utilitary
Comment=Connect or disconnect my headset Sony MDR 1000X
Exec="/home/aho/.local/bin/toggle-mdr-1000x.py"
Icon=/home/aho/.local/share/toggle-mdr-1000x/sony-mdr-1000x.png
Name=MDR-1000X
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Version=1.0
```

Now, when I open the dash menu with the super key / windows key and type 'mdr', the entry shows up, I press enter and **BAM!**, it connects / disconnects.